# How to convert the multiple rows header having date string to Column value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, numpy

Data Dict:

```
{
    "PI No.": {
        0: "Date  :03/31/2023",
        1: "009331",
        2: "009331",
        3: "Date  :03/30/2023",
        4: "009323",
        5: "Date  :03/29/2023",
        6: "009302",
        7: "009302",
    },
    "GRN No.": {
        0: nan,
        1: 19614.0,
        2: 19614.0,
        3: nan,
        4: 19603.0,
        5: nan,
        6: 19576.0,
        7: 19576.0,
    },
    "Supplier Name": {
        0: nan,
        1: "Supplier 1",
        2: "Supplier 1",
        3: nan,
        4: "Supplier 2",
        5: nan,
        6: "Supplier 1",
        7: "Supplier 2",
    },
    "Item": {
        0: nan,
        1: "Item 1",
        2: "Item 2",
        3: nan,
        4: "Item 2",
        5: nan,
        6: "Item 1",
        7: "Item 2",
    },
}
```

[image]

How to achieve the below result.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
out = (df.assign(Date= df["PI No."].str.extract("Date :(.*)").ffill())
         .loc[~df["PI No."].str.startswith("Date")])
```

Output :

```
print(out)
​
   PI No.  GRN No. Supplier Name    Item        Date
1  009331  19614.0    Supplier 1  Item 1  03/31/2023
2  009331  19614.0    Supplier 1  Item 2  03/31/2023
4  009323  19603.0    Supplier 2  Item 2  03/30/2023
6  009302  19576.0    Supplier 1  Item 1  03/29/2023
7  009302  19576.0    Supplier 2  Item 2  03/29/2023
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with forward filling missing values by mask by testing second column for missing values:

```
m = df['GRN No.'].isna()
df = df.assign(Date=df['PI No.'].where(m).replace('Date :','', regex=True).ffill())[~m]
print (df)
   PI No.  GRN No. Supplier Name    Item        Date
1  009331  19614.0    Supplier 1  Item 1  03/31/2023
2  009331  19614.0    Supplier 1  Item 2  03/31/2023
4  009323  19603.0    Supplier 2  Item 2  03/30/2023
6  009302  19576.0    Supplier 1  Item 1  03/29/2023
7  009302  19576.0    Supplier 2  Item 2  03/29/2023
```